# Picture position differs on second run using beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, positioning, diagrams

Is it possible that a picture is positioned differently on the first and second run of XeLaTeX?

I use the beamer class and the tikz package. My code is

```
  \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
    \begin{frame}[plain]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
       \node[at=(current page.center)]{
            \includegraphics[width=\dimexpr(\paperwidth-2cm)]{muenchhausen.jpg}
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: It always takes two runs to correctly position nodes when using `remember picture,overlay`.

Comment: Normal behaviour

Comment: Background for this behaviour is that you want your image to be oriented based on the page. So the first latex run is necessary to collect all the information needed.

Comment: Thanks for you all. @TorbjørnT. , could you please write this as an answer so that I could accept it?